# Set here-api InfoBubble to hide its close button

Tags: here-api

From the CSS I can tell the here-api can set a css class on the infobubble that hides the close button. How do I use it?

Update:

Here is a link to the css provided by HERE: https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css

In it there is styling to hide the close icon in the infobubble if this class "H_ib_noclose" were to be set higher in the DOM.

```
.H_ib_noclose .H_ib_close {display: none;}
.H_ib_noclose .H_ib_body {padding: 0 0 0 0;}
```

I can tell that is should be set higher the the div that has the class of `H_ib_body`.

So does HERE provide the method that adds the class?

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: Question is too general . Could you please provide some more explanation and code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think, there is a direct method which uses this class. You could add the class using the "addClass" method of InfoBubble.

```
currentBubble.addClass("H_ib_noclose")
```